# How to select temporary tables in Temporary Tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, tempdb

Currently, I have some temp tables as this format "#A0089D2C", "#A0232241"

How could I select them to see what are its data?

I tried these queries as below:

```
Select * from #A0089D2C
Select * from tempdb.dbo.#A0089D2C
```

But I got the error:

```
Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#A0089D2C'.
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: is it a permission to database error?

Comment: hi @SnakeFoot, I updated the question with detail error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, only that user who created the local temporary table can access it within the scope. 
That means, local temporary table (# tables) can be accessed within the same scope by the same user while global temporary table(## tables) can be accessed among all the users until the last user session that references the table disconnects.

you can check table schema via below trick:

- Right click on Tempdb database
- Task > Export Data

[image]

- Keep source database as TempDb
- Select destination (Remember: you can not transfer data)
- On Select source table and view form you will see "Edit mapping". Click on that to see table structure

[image]

but if you are really enthusiastic to see data in temporary table then check out this awesome post about [viewing another session's Temporary table](http://web.archive.org/web/20180409190701/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/14/viewing-another-session-s-temporary-table.aspx) by Paul White

Answer (score -1):

this should work, at least if the temp-table exists at the moment.

```
Select * from tempdb.dbo.#A0089D2C
```

See, temp tables are like the Schrodinger cat, they exists and they don't in the same time ;)

Comment: hi SnakeFoot, I updated the question with detail error. Thanks.